# print value from extra_context

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

How to print the values in extra_context in the template

```
def getgeneric(request, page=0, paginate_by=20, **kwargs):
    page_size = 1
    return list_detail.object_list(
    request,
    queryset=Post.objects.published(),
    paginate_by=page_size,
    page=page,
    extra_context={'my' : 1},
    **kwargs
  )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same as usual context object. In your case it will be accessible by `my`

Comment: When i say {{my}} i get an empty value

Comment: By the sound of your comments to @srusskih's answer below, you're now happy that `{{ my }}` works?

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/generic-views/#django-views-generic-list-detail-object-list

`{{ extra_context.my }}`

**UPDATE**

I was wrong.

**`urls.py`**

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

from t1.models import T

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^$', 'django.views.generic.list_detail.object_list', {
        'queryset': T.objects.all(),
        'extra_context': {
            'my':1
        }
    })
)
```

with template: **`t1/templates/t1/t_list.html`**

```
{{ my }}
<hr>
{{ extra_context.my }}
```

return

```
1
<hr>
```

Comment: I still gives an empty value.If anything that i am doing wrong please give me examples..